# Как узнать что были изменения значений во вложенных контролах формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на ней размещены контроллы (textbox, checkbox...).

Как во внешнем, относительно класса формы, коде узнать, что были изменения значений в дочерних контролах?

Comment: практически у всех контролов есть  события <что-то>Changed. Подписываетесь на него и получаете измененное значение. Если нужно быть уверенным, что значение отличается от исходного, дублируйте это значение во внутреннем поле и сравнивайте с новым.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Я думал, что возможно есть некое событие у формы "Изменение любого контролла".

Comment: нет, если вам нужно передать событие за пределы формы, его нужно обработать и вызвать инициировать специально для этого созданное событие самой формы. Это событие нужно создать самостоятельно.

Comment: Как-то надо переформулировать вопрос. чтобы было понятно в чем проблема с первого прочтения. А то кто-то уже минус влепил, хотя в общем-то вопрос не так уж плох, только оформлен плохо =)

Comment: Ну... с этим проблема. я ответ получил. Спасибо.

Comment: Так немного лучше. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В контролах, которые позволяют редактирование значений, есть событие, которое сообщает об изменении данного значения (для TextBox - событие TextBox.TextChanged).
2. Если нужно узнать о событии некоторого контрола, который является частью составного контрола или формы, то в составном контроле нужно создать событие(я) для оповещения внешнего кода и инициировать это событие(я) при обработке событий вложенных контролов. Маршрутизации событий "из коробки" в WinForms не предусмотрено.